# npm start to run some scripts in silent mode

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have multiple scripts in package.json, most of them call some .js e.g. "copyResources" bellow. If I will run "npm run -s copyResources" in shell, it will execute silently. So far so good. But I would like to run "npm start" which will execute copyResource silently, example bellow, but this is not working (it's not silent). :( 
Later I will have more scripts in "start" and I want to run some of them silently and some of them not. Thats the case why I can't just do npm start -s ...

```
"scripts": {
"copyResources": "echo 'Copy resources  =>' && node ./bin/copyResources.js",
"start": "npm run -s copyResources"
```

}

Thank you very much!